# Invalid bean definition with name 'offlineTokenServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]

Tags: java, s4sdk

Thank you for [supporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318790/how-to-run-downloaded-app-router-via-service-marketplace/53326776#53326776) to run the `approuter` package in locally.

Now Getting below exception while running [firstapp](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/) in locally.

I add `xs.appname` `xs.uaa.clientid` `xs.uaa.identityzone` `xs.uaa.verificationkey` , but getting same issue only.

Please suggest me which values have to set with `Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES`

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser - Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
[localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'offlineTokenServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'offlineTokenServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser.getAttribute(SAPVcapServicesParser.java:34)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.parseVcapServices(SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:44)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.readVcapServices(SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:67)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.resolvePlaceholder(SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.resolvePlaceholder(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver.resolvePlaceholder(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:264)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:225)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `VCAP_SERVICES` as an environment variable to your local container as indicated by the error message `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set`. To do so please provide the environment variable with the corresponding parameters like they are when binding a real XSUAA instance to your CloudFoundry microservice. For local deployments your `VCAP_SERVICES` has to have at least the following parameters where the `verificationkey` property needs to match the signature of your JWT. Furthermore, the `tags` attribute is crucial.

> For Mac/Unix

```
export VCAP_SERVICES='{
  "xsuaa":[
  {
    "credentials": {
      "clientid":"testClient",
      "clientsecret":"dummy-clientsecret",
      "identityzone":"uaa",
      "url":"dummy-url",
      "verificationkey":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBI...QIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    },
    "tags":["xsuaa"]
  }]
}'
```

If you provide the environment variable correctly, you should see the following message in your local environment log output:

`INFO: Got from VCAP_SERVICES: identityzone=uaa`

Comment: Philipp, I did set `VCAP_SERVICES` in my enviroment variables, But not working. Please [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368642/error-com-sap-xs2-security-commons-sapofflinetokenservices-error-in-loading-th) me what I missed. My local environment is windows 10.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, It's working with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368642/error-com-sap-xs2-security-commons-sapofflinetokenservices-error-in-loading-th/53369699#53369699)