# RestTemplate API call between microservice is Not working

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have 2 microservices based on SAP SDK 3.0 archetype binded by the same xsuaa service.From the first microservice A, I wanted to call the second microservice B by using rest template. It fails to call, as it is not able to authenticate. Can you find my approach is right?
Sharing the code below along with the error screenshot

[image: Code Screenshot]

Error:
<200,document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHpOk.jpg))+";path=/";document.cookie="signature=pim93tQhbcWCYYAiFxYkwrHBY%2Fs%3D;path=/";location="https://xxxxx.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-Ledify!t7251&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Flogin%2Fcallback",{x-request-id=[k8h8rf33], x-frame-options=[SAMEORIGIN], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Content-Type=[text/html], Content-Security-Policy=[script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'], Date=[Wed, 01 Apr 2020 11:23:01 GMT], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[620]}>

Note : localhost:5000 is my local approuter port and it is configured to call the second microservice which I have tested it in browser

Updated:

I have updated with getToken() but I am getting the below error in my local approuter.

Error Response:

[image: Approuter Log]

xsapp.json Route

{
    "source": "/notif-mock/(.*)",
    "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
    "destination": "notif-mock",
    "csrfProtection": true
  }

FYI, I have used the local approuter setup as per this post [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318790/how-to-run-downloaded-app-router-via-service-marketplace)

Comment: Hi, Arun, if what you posted is a `response` then it says `200`?  Can you please elaborate a bit more:
- Is it some local testing environment?
- What exactly fails and at what step?
- Can you show a stack trace of your request after failure?
- To also log payloads you can use: 
`-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.http.wire=debug`
Why do you think it's an auth issue in the first place?
Have you tested it without auth?

Comment: Also, please, let us know the exact SDK version you're currently using. There were some changes lately related to JWT handling. I recommend updating to version 3.16.1 and checking our release notes: https://help.sap.com/doc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html

Comment: though the response is 200, the expected response is not correct..I am just calling an simple hello world API which would give me a simple JSON response.  Its an auth issue because when i change the approuter authentication type from xsuaa to none,it works.

Comment: Currently, am using SAP SDK 3.9.0

Answer (score 1):

In the following line, you are concatenating a String with `DecodedJWT`:

```java
String encodedAuth = "Bearer " + getJWTTokenDetails();
```

But `DecodedJWT` does not implement a `toString()` method. You must use `getToken()` instead.

**Hint:** For easier support handling please copy/paste your code, because text in screenshot cannot efficiently be referenced.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. As per the comment, I have used the getToken() method. but the error still persists. I have updated the question with approuter screenshot. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Arun,

Thanks for providing all the additional details. [I recommend updating to SDK Version 3.16.1](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sap.cloud.sdk*%20AND%20v:3.16.1) and testing if it solves your issue.

I do it because version 3.9.0 which you're using at the moment has an incomplete implementation of security scenarios invoked by `XSUAA`.

We fixed many issues related to the handling of `XSUAA` and `JWT` validation in release `3.15.1`. [Please, check release notes for details.](https://help.sap.com/doc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html).

If even after update your issue persists, we'll have to see how we can reproduce it or get more logs data from you as a response only doesn't provide enough clue on where it fails.

Hope it helps!